# Remotely passing parameters from PS to batches

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameter-passing, invoke-command

I have read the Q/A already available and found no answer for my (maybe too simple?) case.

I have a PS function which:
1) put a local .bat file into a remote machine (target)
2) calls the remote .bat (through invoke-command) passing it a parameter
3) wait for the successful completion of the remote .bat
4) delete the .bat from the target machine

My problem is that everything runs perfectly but...the parameter is not displayed!

The code of the PS script is:

```
function Run-BatchFile ($computer,$dbn, [string]$batLocation)
{
$sessions = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer -Credential elsmith
Copy-Item -Path $batLocation -Destination "\\$computer\C$\temp" #copy the file locally on the machine where it will be executed
$batfilename = Split-Path -Path $batLocation -Leaf
Invoke-Command -Session $sessions -ScriptBlock {param($batfilename) &  cmd.exe /c "C:\Temp\$batfilename $dbn" } -ArgumentList $batfilename -AsJob   
-ArgumentList $batfilename -AsJob
Get-job | Wait-Job   
Remove-Item -Path "\\$computer\C$\Temp\$batfilename" -Force 
Remove-PSSession -Session $sessions 
}
Run-BatchFile SERVERNAME JOHN "C:\Temp\test_remote_called.bat"
```

The code of the invoked script is just:

```
set DB=%1
echo Test of %DB% was successful >> c:\temp\output.txt
exit /B
```

The output is:

```
Test of  was successful
```

I'm sure there must be a trivial way to solve this problem: am I doing a gross mistake? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Use quotes for each parameter ```/c "C:\Temp\$batfilename" "$dbn"```, also try escaping them with a backtick: ```/c `"C:\Temp\$batfilename`" `"$dbn`"```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Tavo! However, before reading your answer, I changed the logic of the scriptblock using a direct powershell "start-process" call instead of "cmd.exe /c" and I passed the involved parameters with the common "parm" within the scriptblock and it worked! I take your suggestion for the future if I will have to call some .bat scripts through "cmd.exe /c ". Thank you.